# Spring bean definition - get bean class

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-bean

I'm trying the get Bean class name without initialize the bean.
I need to know the class , I could get the bean from applicationContext and to check the class name from the bean instance, But I want to know the class with out actually creating/init the bean..
Is it possible ?

```
 Object bean = applicationContext.getBean("beanName");
 bean.getClass();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this after creating the `ApplicationContext`. Most `ApplicationContext` implementations will `refresh()` themselves and force instantiation of the beans.

What you can do is create a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` in which you get the target bean definition and check the bean class.

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    String className = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("").getBeanClassName();
}
```

But note, as the javadoc for `getBeanClassName()` states

> Hence, do not consider this to be the definitive bean type at runtime
>   but rather only use it for parsing purposes at the individual bean
>   definition level.

So use it with a grain of salt.

---

If you give us more details as to what you are trying to accomplish, there might be alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The code provided by Sotirious will not work for the beans that have parent beans and for the beans that are defined using Java Config or using `@Component` annotation (and similar annotatios like `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component`).

Just an extension which checks if it is `AnnotatedBeanDefinition` or if the bean has a parent:

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    for (String beanDefinitionName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        String beanClassName = getBeanClassName(beanDefinitionName, beanFactory);
    }
}

private String getBeanClassName(String beanName, ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    String beanClassName;
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
    if (beanDefinition instanceof AnnotatedBeanDefinition) {
        AnnotationMetadata metadata = ((AnnotatedBeanDefinition) beanDefinition).getMetadata();
        beanClassName = metadata.getClassName();
    } else {
        beanClassName = beanDefinition.getBeanClassName();
        while (beanClassName == null) {
            BeanDefinition parentBeanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanDefinition.getParentName());
            beanClassName = parentBeanDefinition.getBeanClassName();
            beanDefinition = parentBeanDefinition;
        }
    }

    return beanClassName;
}
```

Note, this approach will not work in the case factory method is used. As Java Doc says:

> Also, this may just be the class that a factory method is called on, or it may even be empty in case of a factory bean reference that a method is called on. Hence, do *not* consider this to be the definitive bean type at runtime but rather only use it for parsing purposes at the individual bean definition level.